# Module has been externalized for browser compatibility error

Tags: node.js, angular, vite

In my Angular app I'm getting an error when using `console.log();`

Error: Module "console" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "console.log" in client code.  See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.

After researching the links I cannot see how console.log applies to node modules. Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `console` polyfill is available via [vite-plugin-node-polyfils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills) package.

Install via npm and use in the config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
})
```

This package provides the following polyfills.

> 

```
[
  '_stream_duplex',
  '_stream_passthrough',
  '_stream_readable',
  '_stream_transform',
  '_stream_writable',
  'assert',
  'buffer',
  'child_process',
  'cluster',
  'console',
  'constants',
  'crypto',
  'dgram',
  'dns',
  'domain',
  'events',
  'fs',
  'http',
  'http2',
  'https',
  'module',
  'net',
  'os',
  'path',
  'process',
  'punycode',
  'querystring',
  'readline',
  'repl',
  'stream',
  'string_decoder',
  'sys',
  'timers',
  'timers/promises',
  'tls',
  'tty',
  'url',
  'util',
  'vm',
  'zlib',
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlie! However, this was within an Angular / Nx project. I dont believe there's a vite config, is there? Also the problem mysteriously stopped.